# Check if a file exists, using another user (sudo -u)

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I want to check if a file exists `[ -f /path/to/file ]` using another user.

So, I added:

```
USER1        ALL=(USER2)     /bin/mkdir, /usr/bin/git, /bin/echo
```

to the sudoers file.

The problem is, when I try to execute

```
USER1:~$ sudo -u USER2 [ -f /path/to/file ] && echo "1"
```

I get the following:

```
Sorry, user USER1 is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/[ -f /path/to/file ]' as USER2 on localhost.
```

So, the question here is: How do I enable that on the sudoers file?

---

**Solution**

I added `/usr/bin/test` to the sudoers file, and instead of going with this:

```
USER1:~$ sudo -u USER2 [ -f /path/to/file ] && echo "1"
```

I actually used:

```
USER1:~$ sudo -u USER2 /usr/bin/test -f /path/to/file && echo "1"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to execute `/usr/bin/[` but haven't given the user permission to. There are two ways you could do this.

The first is to allow the user to execute `/usr/bin/[` (which is the [`test`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/test.1.html) program). This would allow the user to perform any kind of test on any file. You can also use `test` instead of `[`, which may be more obvious as to what's happening.

```
USER1   ALL=(USER2) /bin/mkdir, /usr/bin/git, /bin/echo, /usr/bin/[, /usr/bin/test
```

And then run:

```
sudo -u USER2 [ -f /path/to/file ] && echo "1"
```

or

```
sudo -u USER2 test -f /path/to/file && echo "1"
```

The second option is to write a wrapper script and allow the user to execute that. For example, with the following in `/usr/local/bin/exists`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
[ -f "$1" ]
```

And this in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
USER1   ALL=(USER2) /bin/mkdir, /usr/bin/git, /bin/echo, /usr/local/bin/exists
```

The user could run:

```
sudo -u USER2 /usr/local/bin/exists /path/to/file && echo "1"
```

Comment: I tried option 1, and still the same error: `Sorry, user USER1 is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/[ -f /path/to/file ]' as USER2 on localhost.`. And I want to avoid the second option, as I don't want to create another file to run that. There's any bits missing on the first option? I also tried `/usr/bin/[ .*` and it didn't work.

Comment: Although your answer didn't solve the problem, it pointed me to the right direction. If someone needs the final solution, please refer to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @jlcd Strange, it works for me. I've added that method to my answer.